# Bootstrap datetime picker and DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I have datetime picker in my form:

```html
<div class="input-group date" data-custom-datepicker="true">
<div class="input-group-addon datepicker-custom-btn">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>

<input type="text" class="picker" value="">
<input type="text" name="SelectionDeadline" class="form-control datepicker-custom valid" 
    value="" data-val="true" tooltip="DD-MM-YYYY" id="SelectionDeadline" 
    aria-describedby="SelectionDeadline-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

The format I want is:

```js
$('#SelectionDeadline').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'
});
```

My model have prop:

```cs
public DateTime? SelectionDeadline { get; set; }
```

Because this field can be null, so when I submit form with date set to `"20-09-2016 13:07"`

In model `SelectionDeadline` prop is `null` but when I try to get value by `Request.Form`:

```
var form = Request.Form;
var val = form["SelectionDeadline"];
```

val is `"20-09-2016 13:07"`

So my question is why ASP cannot pass this value to `DateTime?` it is because of nullable type or `"dd-MM-yyyy"` format?

**@EDIT:**

So, basicly what i did for now is modification to my `ViewModel`:

```
 public string selectionDeadlines { get; set; }
 private DateTime? selectionDeadlined { get; set; }
 public DateTime? SelectionDeadline
 {
     get
     {
         if (selectionDeadlined == null)
         {
             DateTime dt;
             selectionDeadlined = DateTime.TryParseExact(selectionDeadlines, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) ? dt : null as Nullable<DateTime>;
         }
         return selectionDeadlined;
     }
     set
     {
         selectionDeadlined = value;
     }
 }
```

And now I'm saving value downloaded from `datetime picker` as string `selectionDeadlines`, it is not perfect solution but if I will find better I will let you know!

Comment: Does the culture in your server accept dates in that format? (if not, you will need to change the culture or create a custom ModelBinder - it has nothing to do with the property being `nullable`)

Comment: Yes, i have proper culture, in other page I'm using datepicker without time and it works just fine

Comment: To test it use `DateTime.Parse(val);` to see if its returns a valid `DateTime`

Comment: Nope, it throws "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." exception

Comment: Then it does not match the culture on your server :)

Comment: So after changing culture to "pl-PL" 'DateTime.Parse(val);' works but 'SelectionDeadline ' prop is still null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123697/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-carlos28).

Answer (score 1):

its because of 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm' format,
 use

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

inside model

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's problem. OP is using a jquery plugin and that attribute only applies when you use `EditorFor()` to generate the browsers datepicker - and in any case it wrong since it must be in ISO format to bind correctly (`DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-yyyy}"`)